# How to render a site locally with source code in hand?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, template-engine

I downloaded the whole package of [Bootstrap(the middle one)](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and was looking into its hierarchy. I found out that this source code contains the site http://getbootstrap.com/.

For example, it has the `html` file of [getting-started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) page looks like this:

```
---
layout: default
title: Getting started
slug: getting-started
lead: "An overview of Bootstrap, how to download and use, basic templates and examples, and more."
---


{% include getting-started/download.html %}
{% include getting-started/whats-included.html %}
{% include getting-started/grunt.html %}
{% include getting-started/template.html %}
{% include getting-started/examples.html %}
{% include getting-started/tools.html %}
{% include getting-started/community.html %}
{% include getting-started/disabling-responsiveness.html %}

<!-- Cross link to new migration page -->
<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info" id="migration">
  <h4>Migrating from v2.x to v3.x</h4>
  <p>Looking to migrate from an older version of Bootstrap to v3.x? Check out <a href="../migration">our migration guide</a>.</p>
</div>

{% include getting-started/browser-device-support.html %}
{% include getting-started/third-party-support.html %}
{% include getting-started/accessibility.html %}
{% include getting-started/license.html %}
{% include getting-started/translations.html %}
```

I know it can be rendered into static site by some kind of template render engine. But how to do it?

Comment: From their [download page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download): Requires a Less compiler and [some setup](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt).

Comment: That is [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) above the HTML. You can install Jekyll on your computer and render the site locally. If your just looking for bootstrap you can [download it] (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download).

Comment: @David Corbin After a few trial and error, it worked! It was simpler than I thought.